# How do I handle NaN in mongoengine: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am defining a document model using mongoengine. I have a pre-existing collection with a variable number of fields (hence `'strict': False`).

When I try to retrieve the records:

```
ClassName.objects[:1]
```

I receive the following error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

However, the stack trace does not show which field is causing the issue.

I am inclined to think it's because some fields contain `NaN` where I have defined it as a `FloatField()` (mongo calls the field type `Double`).

1. Any suggestions as to how I can find out which field is causing the issue?
2. Could `NaN` be causing the error shown above?

I wasn't able to find anything regarding `NaN` in the mongoengine documentation.

```
{
  "field_one" : NaN,
  "field_two" : NaN
  ....
}

class ClassName(db.Document):
    field_one = me.FloatField()
    field_two = me.FloatField()

    meta = {
      'strict': False,
      'collection': 'collection_name'
    }
```

Comment: How are you using NaN in python? Normally Python doesn't have NaN.

Comment: pandas `DataFrame` have NaN's